# Interval Based Report Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need **First Login** and **Last Logout** report for CC agents, I have information of every login and logout they perform during their shift (i.e Logout for lunch/smoke/breaktime etc).

**We have the Following shifts:**

```
S.No    Shift         Possible Login    Possible Log Out
1.      08 – 04       8: 07             16:05
2.      10 – 06       10:03             18:09
3.      04 – 00       16:08             00:02
4.      06 – 02       18:04             02:01
5.      00 – 08       23:57             08:04
```

I have this view for collecting relevant information as below:

[image: Login Log Out Details]

Problem with this report is that if I am generating a single day report as **20/06/2016** then I am not able to capture information on Shift S.No. (3,4,5) because there is a day change.

For Example:

> **Agent Login Date/Time is:** 20/06/2016 18:10

And

> **Agent Logout Date/Time is:** 21/06/2016 02:05

I need something like to have Interval column where day starts at **20/06/2016 03:00** and day ends at **21/06/2016 03:00** how to achieve this Interval ? Or if you have any other Idea for this report requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, based on the view you've shown there, you need to provide data for all the people that were working on, say, *20/06/2016*? If that's so, I believe you could select from the view all the people whose

```
CAST(FirstLogin AS date) = '20160620'
```

If you needed to also include the people who started working on *19/06/2016* and ended on *20/06/2016* then you would do the same for *LastLogOut*.

In addition, if you were to write it as a dynamic query, if you needed to provide a report for yesterday for example, you'd substitute the *20/06/2016* from the where clause with

```
CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS date)
```

Comment: Can you please show me a query output ? or complete syntax

Comment: So, to imitate your view I've created a table and put inside the first and last row of your image, and also added another one that goes after midnight as follows:

http://i.imgur.com/xattnlS.png

Now from this using what I wrote you can get all the ones that started on the date you want:

http://i.imgur.com/Dm6Zt1h.png . You expand this dynamically so that instead of a date you use the above given "formula".